# Why must I call sed a second time after substituting spaces with newlines?

Tags: sed, posix

Given a file, I want to make a list of all the bytes it contains in octal format, each byte on its own line.

Why does this work:

```
#!/bin/sh --

newline='
'

od -v -A n -t o1 -- /tmp/file | \
sed -e "s/ /\\${newline}/g" | \
sed -e '/^$/d'
```

and not this:

```
#!/bin/sh --

newline='
'

od -v -A n -t o1 -- /tmp/file | \
sed -e "s/ /\\${newline}/g" -e '/^$/d'
```

Why do I have to call sed two separate times to get the job done?

For reference, the output from `od`, without further processing, may look something like the following:

```
         047 124 167 141 163 040 142 162 151 154 154 151 147 054 040 141
         156 144 040 164 150 145 040 163 154 151 164 150 171 040 164 157
         166 145 163 012 011 104 151 144 040 147 171 162 145 040 141 156
         144 040 147 151 155 142 154 145 040 151 156 040 164 150 145 040
         167 141 142 145 072 012 101 154 154 040 155 151 155 163 171 040
         167 145 162 145 040 164 150 145 040 142 157 162 157 147 157 166
         145 163 054 012 011 101 156 144 040 164 150 145 040 155 157 155
         145 040 162 141 164 150 163 040 157 165 164 147 162 141 142 145
         056 012
```

Comment: Note that with GNU `od`, you can use `-w1` to output one number per line. See also BSD's `hexdump -ve '/1 "%03o\n"'`. And there's also `od ... | tr -cs 0-7 '[\n*]' | grep .`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each `sed` expression acts on the whole of the pattern space.  At the start of a cycle, a line is read into the pattern space, then `sed` applies each given expression to this data.

In the second variation of your code, you insert newlines into the pattern space with the substitution.  The second expression, `/^$/d`, will still act on the pattern space as a whole, not on each individual line in the pattern space, which means that the pattern will not match (since the buffer is non-empty), and the pattern space will not be deleted. Changing `/^$/d` into `s/\n\{2,\}//g` would delete any run of two or more consecutive newline-characters (these would create empty lines in the output), which *would* have worked.

This is in contrast to the first variation of the code, where the second `sed` reads the output of the first `sed`.  In this case, the second `sed` will read each generated line *individually*, and deletes the ones that are empty.

In short: Adding newlines into the pattern space will not make `sed` reconsider each generated line as individual input for the remaining expressions.

---

An alternate solution:

```
od -v -A n -t o1 -- /tmp/file |
sed -e 's/ \{2,\}//g' -e 'y/ /\n/'
```

The first `sed` expression, `s/ \{2,\}//g`, gets rid of any run of two or more consecutive spaces, and then the second expression converts the remaining spaces to newlines (`\n` is allowed with the `y` command, even in POSIX `sed`).

Or, you can delete all flanking spaces before converting all remaining spaces to newlines:

```
od -v -A n -t o1 -- /tmp/file |
sed -e 's/^ *//' -e '$s/ *$//' -e 'y/ /\n/'
```

(Note that only the last line of output from `od` may possibly have trailing spaces, which is why I use `$` as the address for the second expression.)

Or, it may be more straightforward with `awk`:

```
od -v -A n -t o1 -- /tmp/file |
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) print $i }'
```

Comment: Just to clarify, did `sed` fail to do what I wanted it to do because I included an escaped newline in the replacement text of the first `-e` expression? Are there other gotchas I should be aware of when chaining multiple expressions together with the `-e` option?

Comment: @HaroldFischer No, it failed because the the regular expression `/^$/` never matches. It never matches because the pattern space is never empty (given the input from `od` and the previous substitution). It's never empty because you insert newlines into it.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out and forgive my ignorance. Are you saying, that, e.g., `echo abc | sed -e "s/a/\\${newline}" -e '/^$/d'` does not work as I would expect because it treats the internal result $'a\nc' as being a single "line"?

Comment: @HaroldFischer Yes, in a sense. But that's only partly true. It would be more correct to say that `^` matches at the start of the pattern space, and `$` at the end, rather than to talk about "lines". The expression `/^$/d` would therefore delete the contents of the pattern space and start the next cycle only if the  pattern space was empty (which it clearly is not).

Answer (score 0):

That's because the empty lines exists only in the output file, after the substitutions have been made. Why not

```
od -v -An -to1 -w1 -- file
```

?

Comment: Note that [tag:posix] tag.  The `-w` option is not a POSIX option.